# Get file posted with wget in php

Tags: php, wget

How would I be able to get the file shared in this line?

```
wget --post-file=/home/bin/tmp/results.txt http://192.120.203.168:2224/test.php
```

Comment: What do mean by "get the file shared"? Do you understand what that line of code does?

Comment: Actually I just understood a bit of that line. I just tried it since I've seen it in a post. Then I got confused as to how would I be able to get the file it posted..

Comment: If you ran that line of code, that means file `/home/bin/tmp/results.txt` is on the same server and you have access to it.

Comment: ahh so it means that it's not posting or transmitting the file to the URL (http://192.120.203.168:2224/test.php)?

Comment: That command DOES send (by POST request) the local file to that address. Read [more about wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget). Where did you get that command from?

Comment: I just get it from someone's answer here in SO. I got puzzled, so I tried it. Anyway thanks for your help.. thanks for the pointers.